# Obtaining GUID for Existing USB Device on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, usb, wmi, guid, registry

I need to find the GUID for an existing USB device attached to my Windows XP system.  How can this be done using WMI or the registry?  Or, is there another avenue that I should explore?  Thanks.

**Additional Information:**

I need to find the GUID for a specific known device; it is not expected to change.  If I need to write a little program, use some tool, or look somewhere in the Windows system to find this information, it's all the same to me.

Comment: I assume you mean the device class GUID?  Are you trying to do this programmatically or manually?  Are you trying to get the GUID for a specific known device, or are you trying to look up an arbitrary device's GUID at runtime?

Comment: @Josh Kelley: I added some additional information to my original question, which hopefully answers your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a specific known device, the easiest way I've found is to open the .inf file for that device's driver (if you have the driver); it should be clearly indicated there.

You can probably also poke around under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB.

Comment: Accepted because you beat me to it.

Answer (score 5):

Control Panel > Device Manager > Right Click on Device > Properties > Details Tab > Change 'Property' to Driver Key > Guid will be displayed in 'value' section

Comment: I just tried that, and got 88BAE032-5A81-49f0-BC3D-A4FF138216D6, which is the GUID for USB device class. I believe all USB devices have that GUID

Answer (score 1):

[DevViewer from Symantec](http://service1.symantec.com/SUPPORT/ent-security.nsf/ppfdocs/2007511906325898?Open&dtype=corp&src=&seg=&om=1&om_out=prod) also seems to do the trick.